# Async/Await with Tasks.WhenAll in For Loop Not Running In Parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

tI'm doing a data migration where I have a long list of pets that I am looping through to perform the migration. In order to migrate each pet a lot of business logic has to be done. I'd like to have multiple migration tasks running at once to speed this along, but the async addition to the below seems to be operating that same as it would synchronously. I've found several stack overflow responses and blog posts about this, but for some reason this still isn't working.

I tried to keep the code below to the minimum required, but if more context is needed I can provide that.

```cs
public static async Task MigrationAsync(MyDbContext myContext)
{
    await MainMigrationAsync(myContext);

}

public static async Task MainMigrationAsync(MyDbContext myContext)
{
    var pets = myContext.Pets.ToList();

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var eachPet = 0; eachRelation < pets.Count; eachRelation++)
    {
        var task = SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync(myContext, pets[eachPet]);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll();

    myContext.SaveChanges();
}

public static async Task SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync(MyDbContext myContext, Pet pet)
{
    //these need to run synchronously for each pet, but need multiple pet tasks to be running at once
    MigrationMethodOne(myContext);
    MigrationMethodTwo(myContext);
    MigrationMethodThree(myContext);
    MigrationMethodFour(myContext);
}
```

Comment: You appear to be using a single EF context in a multithreaded way.   This is not allowed, and should be throwing exceptions.

Comment: Is there any locking of any kind in `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` ?

Comment: No locking at the moment. Good point about the dbcontext. Will need to look into strategies here too.

Comment: Are you running this code from the main thread? If so there will not be any threading going on except possibly internally by the database access layer.

Comment: Please note that everything in `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` will run *synchronously* up to the first `await`.

Comment: What does `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` do? Is the work CPU bound?

Comment: yeah, this is .net core 3.1 console app. these are getting called from main.

Comment: `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` calls several functions to perform various db operations

Comment: @PaulDeVito Can you share?

Comment: @MattiasLarsson I want the method calls in `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` to run synchronously (they need to), but I'd like to be running multiple `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` tasks at once so i can, in essence, migrate multiple pets at once.

Comment: @PaulDeVito When you say _these need to run synchronously_, do you mean that they need to run sequentially? This isn't the same as synchronously; you could make `MigrationMethodOne`, `MigrationMethodTwo` etc. async and await each of them.

Comment: Jonathan, yeah, I do mean synchronously. Data from earlier methods is used downstream in later methods.

Comment: The problem in this particular application is that EF Core does not allow parallel access to the DbContext (as @Neil already pointed out).

Answer (score 2):

**Important:** Since EF core doesn't allow parallel usage of a `DbContext` you must provide one `DbContext` per "job".

And there is no `await` in the `SingleLongRunningPetMigrationAsync` method, so it should not be of type `async Task`, just `void`.

You could for instance use a "[Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)" in your scenario (given that each call gets its own `DbContext`).